# use EntityFieldQuery to find user based on profile field value

Tags: database

I have a field within the user's profile set with their payroll. What I'm trying to achieve within my module is find the uid, based on the value of a payroll field.

I've tried a few things, but I can't get it to work. What I'm currently trying is this, but it returns unknown field of user

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();

$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'user')
  ->fieldCondition('user', 'field_user_payroll', $payroll, '=');

$result = $query->execute();
$account = user_load($result);

$wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('user', $account);
$mimemail = $wrapper->mimemail->raw();

watchdog('Photo Import', "Mimemail: %mimemail", 
  array('%mimemail' => $mimemail), WATCHDOG_INFO);
```

Any help would be really appreciated. It's driving me crazy!

Comment: Have you read the docs for `EntityFieldQuery`? Your code is quite far off from what it should be, that's all

Comment: [Community docs for it here](http://drupal.org/node/1343708)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'user')
  ->fieldCondition('field_user_payroll', 'value', $payroll, '=');
$results = $query->execute();

$users = user_load_multiple(array_keys($results['user']));
foreach($users as $user) {
    $wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('user', $account);
    $mimemail = $wrapper->mimemail->raw();

    watchdog('Photo Import', "Mimemail: %mimemail", array('%mimemail' => $mimemail), WATCHDOG_INFO);
}
```

as per [EntityFieldQuery::fieldCondition()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!entity.inc/function/EntityFieldQuery%3a%3afieldCondition/7), [EntityFieldQuery doc](https://drupal.org/node/1343708)

......

Comment: That'll get him so far...what about `$account = user_load($result);` though? ;)

Comment: Right, updated answer, even though I'm not sure what is intented with the mimemail part

Comment: @SebCorbin it looks vaguely like watchdog messages I set sometimes to know "now would ..... happen" if I want to avoid pointless mails during development, for example.

Comment: It's a property added by the mimemail module (in a `hook_node_load()` or something), nothing more sinister than that. @SebCorbin I'd recommend `user_load_multiple(array_keys($result['user']))` instead of loading each separately; that could get very inefficient with a lot of users in the results

Comment: mimemail was only added because this piece of code is being called by cron, so I wanted a watchdog line to look out for. Not going to be using it for anything. Little modification and it's working. I needed to change:

    foreach($result['user'] as $user) {
      $account = user_load($user->uid);

Comment: Note: user_load_multiple(array_keys($result['user'])) is able to load those users more efficient as it can do a single query or a single cache get multiple if you're using entitycache.

Comment: @SebCorbin I want to fetch users based on some matching fields. E.g When a user with role buyer posts job (which is a node), the system automatically fetches users with role seller, matching the fields in the job content type with profile2 fields. How to do it? I am a beginner, so explain a little.