# check if user exists

Tags: 7, users

I want to check if user exists based on some profile2 field. I have tried the following. Works fine. I want to know if it is proper or not. If it is not proper, is there any other way around?

```
function checkUserExistsByProfile($company_id){

        $query = 'SELECT field_somefield_value
        FROM {field_data_field_somefield} AS fn
        WHERE fn.field_somefield_value  =:rids';
        $result = db_query($query, array(':rids' => array($company_id)));

        $field_value = $result->fetchCol();
        return count($field_value);

    }
```

Please suggest.

**UPDATE:**

I have tried solutions suggested by  Mołot, Bulat as follows.

Profile Field name is `field_ngouniqueid`

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'user')
->fieldCondition('field_ngouniqueid', 'value', (int)$company_id, '=');
$results = $query->execute();

$users = user_load_multiple(array_keys($results['user']));
```

But users is an empty array always. But it has a record with value `$company_id`

**Solution:**
it should be **$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'profile2')**

Comment: it is not a good way. "Proper" can be found here - http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/84464/use-entityfieldquery-to-find-user-based-on-profile-field-value/84466#84466

Comment: See [How to use EntityFieldQuery](https://www.drupal.org/node/1343708)

Comment: Please check an updated answer

Comment: be sure to add your solution as an answer and then accept it, so that this question doesn't remain unanswered...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the users filtered based on profile2 field, `field_ngouniqueid` is created through **profile2**

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'profile2')
->fieldCondition('field_ngouniqueid', 'value', (int)$company_id, '=');
$results = $query->execute();

$users = user_load_multiple(array_keys($results['user']));
```